# Запрос в бд где значение !=0 Yii2

Tags: php, yii

Думал что такого полно, но мои поиски не дали результата может не правильно искал.

Нужно написать такой запрос

```
SELECT * FROM table_name Where tab_user_id ='".$user_id."' AND tab_select !=0
```

нашел такую конструкцию но что то не получается выборка

```
tab_name::find()->where(['tab_user_id' => $user_id])->andWhere('not',['tab_select' =>null])->one();
```

Comment: ну так в такой конструкции null написано, а не 0.

Comment: null это пустое значения тогда так `AND tab_select !=' '`

Comment: Это шутка такая? Писать что угодно, но только не то значение, которое должно быть в запросе?

Comment: нет, спасибо за помощь нашел решения

Answer (score 0):

```
$res = \Yii::$app->db->createCommand('SELECT * FROM table_name Where tab_user_id = :id AND tab_select != :tab_select', [':id' => $user_id, ':tab_select' => 0])->execute();
```

Comment: Кто поставил минус можете объяснить почему нельзя использовать такую конструкцию  `$post = Yii::$app->db->createCommand('SELECT * FROM post WHERE id=:id AND status=:status')
           ->bindValues($params)
           ->queryOne();` ведь это написано в документации

Comment: Понятное дело, что через модель model::find работать проще и так и нужно, но у задававшего не получается это по необъяснимым причинам, вот и написал верняковый способ

Comment: Хорошо, это я понял что нужно использовать  ` model::find` но хотелось бы понять почему нельзя использовать `Yii::$app->db->createCommand` почему она медленнее работает или почему ?

Comment: можно использовать и так, таким способом вы не пользуетесь ActiveRecord yii2 и по этому такой метод будет не медленнее а даже быстрее

Comment: Быстрее причем намного, однако вы потеряете все прелести AR + код будет плохо масштабируемым

Comment: Николай Ан можете подробней объяснить или ссылку где можно почитать ` код будет плохо масштабируемым` хочу для себя понять правильность написания кода и в дальнейшем не делать ошибок